# Set Default Program for All Users on Server

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, filetype

I work with a large server environment that's running Windows Server 2003, 2008, and 2012 now on some boxes. We have a custom-built log viewer program that associates with two file types that I'd like to set to be the default program for all users across all boxes, so new users don't have to set the default program themselves on every box they log into.

Ideally I'd like to have a simple registry script we could push out to all machines at once.

I realize this likely means changing the registry entries for either HKCR or HKLM for the file extensions, but adding the program location with %1 extension to \shell\open\command value in HKLM simply opens the program and does not also load the log file. Am I just missing an open and play setting, or am I looking at this entirely wrong?

(And I know the script will need to be different for 2003 and 2008, but changing the version for two scripts isn't hard)

Thanks!

Comment: Does the application even accept arguments?

Comment: Have you made a .REG file and applied it to another server of the same type?